# How to use column numbers in the dplyr filter function

Tags: r, filter, syntax, dplyr, tidyverse

How do I use the `dplyr::filter()` function with column numbers, rather than column names?

As an example, I'd like to pick externally selected columns and return the rows that are all zeros. For example, for a data frame like this

```
> test
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    C001  C007  C008  C020
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    -1    -1     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0
 3     1     1     0     0
 4    -1    -1     0     0
 5     0     0     0    -1
 6     0     0     0     1
 7     0     1     1     0
 8     0     0    -1    -1
 9     1     1     0     0
10     0     0     0     0
```

and a vector `S = c(1,3,4)` How would I pick all the rows in `test` where `all(x==0)`? I can do  this with an `test[apply(test[,S] 1, function(x){all(x==0)},]` but I'd like to use this as part of a `%>%` pipeline.

I have not been able to figure out the `filter()` syntax to use column numbers rather than names. The real data has many more columns (>100) and rows and the column numbers are supplied by an external algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter_at` with `all_vars`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(c(1,3,4), all_vars(.==0))

 C001 C007 C008 C020
1    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: faster, too! a 1.5x speedup. Thanks